# MySQL query to fetch product variants

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to fetch product variant attributes to display on a product page. I would like the following output:

> color: red (size: S, M), green (size: S)

but I'm getting:

> color: red, green
>   size: S, M

This is a simplified version of what I have so far:

```
 PRODUCT TABLE
|    id     |
-------------
|     1     |
|     1     |
|     1     |
```

```
 VARIANT TABLE
|    id     |fk_product_id|
---------------------------
|     1     |       1     |
|     2     |       1     |
|     3     |       1     |
```

```
 ATTRIBUTE TABLE
|fk_variant_id| property |  value    |
--------------------------------------
|     1     |   color   |     red    |
|     1     |    size   |      S     |
|     2     |   color   |     green  |
|     2     |    size   |      S     |
|     3     |   color   |     red   |
|     3     |    size   |      M     |
```

```
$stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT
    attribute.property AS property,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT attribute.value) AS value
FROM product
INNER JOIN variant
    ON product.id=variant.fk_product_id
LEFT JOIN attribute
    ON variant.id=attribute.fk_variant_id
WHERE product_id=:product_id
GROUP BY attribute.property');

$stmt->bindParam(':product_id',$product_id);
$stmt->execute();
$query=$stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($query as $row){
  echo $row['property'].' '.$row['value'].'<br>';
}
```

The end game is something like this:
[image: attribute selection]

Comment: Personally, I can't really understand the point of including a GROUP_CONCAT clause in a PHP parsed query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It effectively creates tables of each attribute (`color` and `size`) and JOINs them to the product and variant.

```
SELECT p.id AS product, c.value AS color, GROUP_CONCAT(s.value) AS sizes
FROM product p
JOIN variant v ON v.fk_product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN attribute c ON c.fk_variant_id = v.id AND c.property = 'color'
LEFT JOIN attribute s ON s.fk_variant_id = v.id AND s.property = 'size'
GROUP BY product, color
```

Output

```
product     color   sizes
1           green   S
1           red     S,M
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=20efee88b464b4527d40ad58124f74a0)

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly. And, I learned something new. :)